# how would you convert the following into yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I am learning yii2 and wanted to know how would you convert the following into yii2 and still be responsive in I was view in a phone, tablet or pc.

This is the following code.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-land-4 "><p class="text-center">
 <a href="consearch.php">
 <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/conbuttscreen.png"
     alt="Find Concierge Services" />
 <strong>CONCIERGE<br/>SERVICES</strong><br/></a></p></div>
```

I wanted to see how to convert it to the yii2 coding for example using the **HTML::a()** or the **HTML::submitButton()** tags found in the **yii\helpers\Html** etc.

Comment: This is something to do with html and css. Not yii i'm afraid

Comment: I was taking about like   `<?= Html::a(Html::img('@web/images/docbuttscreen.png', ['alt'=>'Find Doctor/Health Professional', 'class'=>'img-responsive center-block']), 
           ['/site/docsearch']);`

Comment: can u please edit your question so that it is very clear

Comment: I have updated the Question to try to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the anchor you can do this way

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-land-4 "><p class="text-center">
<?= Html::a('<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="@web/images/conbuttscreen.png"
                 alt="Find Concierge Services" /><strong>CONCIERGE<br/>SERVICES</strong><br/>', ['consearch.php']) ?>
</p></div>
```